# Probability Question from my textbook

Tags: probability

A pack contains m cards, labeled 1, 2,....,m. The cards are dealt
out in a random order, one by one. Given that the label of the kth card dealt is
the largest of the first k cards, what is the probability that it is also the largest in
the whole pack?

Reading probability myself and stuck at some questions.

Answer (score 3):

(You might want this to get double-checked by someone else; my probability is a bit rusty.)

Recall the formula for [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability):
$$ \begin{align} 
P(A \cap B) &= P(A|B)P(B) \\
P(A|B) &= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} 
\end{align}$$

Here, let $A$ be the event that the $k$th card is the largest of the $m$ cards, and $B$ be the 
event that the $k$th card is the largest of the $k$ cards drawn.

Since $A$ implies $B$, $P(A \cap B) = P(A)$. So the probability is $1/m$. 
The probability of event $B$, that the $k$th card is the largest of $k$ cards, without knowing any other information, is $1/k$.

Then $$P(A|B) = \frac{1/m}{1/k} = \frac{k}{m}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability is equal to the probability that the largest of m cards is one of the first k cards, which is $\frac{k}{m}$.